# Omega appears from if result

Tags: conditionals

I am attempting to edit an if statement that I was using in an environment I created.  Previously, the code was

```
\if #1\empty
\else
\textbf{#1.}\hspace{0.5em}%
\fi
```

I want to change it to something like

```
\if #1\empty \textbf{}\hspace{0.5em}
\else
\textbf{#1.}\hspace{0.5em}%
\fi
```

where I could put what I want in the \textbf{}.  But whatever I put in there, I get \Omega printed in front of it.  When left empty like above, it simply prints \Omega.  If #1 is not empty, there is no \Omega.

My code

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\newenvironment{question}[3][]{
\noindent\ignorespaces
\if #1\empty \textbf{}\hspace{0.5em}
\else
\textbf{#1.}\hspace{0.5em}%
\fi
}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{question}{0}{8}\end{question}

\begin{question}[1]{0}{8}\end{question}
\end{document}
```

Any advice on getting rid of this capital omega is very welcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\if` expands the following tokens until it finds two expandable tokens.
If `#1` is empty, then `\empty` is expanded to nothing, then `\textbf`, there it finds these tokens. Expansions:

```
\empty ->
```

`\empty` vanishes, because its definition text is empty.

```
\textbf -> \protect \textbf␣
```

In the context here, `\protect` has the meaning of `\relax`, thus it is the
first non-expandable token.

```
\textbf␣ #1 -> \ifmmode ...\else \hmode@bgroup ... \fi
```

We don't have math mode, thus the `\hmode@bgroup` is expanded:

```
\hmode@bgroup -> \leavevmode \bgroup
\leavevmode -> \unhbox \voidb@x
```

Now we the second non-expandable token is `\unhbox`. Because both tokens are command tokens, the result of `\if` is `true` and the remaining tokens are not removed. `\voidb@x` is executed, now as standalone token, not as argument for `\unhbox`. It's a character constant encoding the box number, which was intended to be used with `\unhbox`.

`\voidb@x` is number 65, defined as `\char"A`. In the current font this gives the uppercase omega.

Also the test fails, if `#1` starts with two equal non-expandable tokens, e.g. `11`.

The following example puts `#1` in the macro `\QuestionFirstParam` and
compares it via `\ifx` with `\empty`, because `\ifx` does not expand the following tokens, instead it compares the next two tokens:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\newenvironment{question}[3][]{%
  \noindent
  \def\QuestionFirstParam{#1}%
  \ifx\QuestionFirstParam\empty
    \leavevmode
    % \textbf{}%
    % \hspace{0.5em}%
  \else
    \textbf{#1.}\hspace{0.5em}%
  \fi
  arg2 = #2, arg3 = #3%
}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{question}{0}{8}\end{question}

\begin{question}[1]{0}{8}\end{question}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Can you explain little bit why the original code prints that omega?

Comment: Of course, `\textbf{}` does nothing apart making TeX spinning its wheels for a while.

Comment: @egreg I haven't removed it, because starting a line with `\hbox{.5em}` does not look too good either. Perhaps it's due to the minimizing part of the MWE.

Comment: `\hspace{.5em}` *does* start a paragraph.

Comment: Thank you, not only did you give a solution, but an in depth explanation, so that I now will not make a similar mistake.  Much appreciated.